# Angular Material custom color property/directive

Tags: angular

How can I define custom Angular Material color on the directive `color` which appears in various Material components:

```
<button mat-button color="accent" (click)="back()">{{ 'Back' | translate }}</button>
<button mat-button color="primary" (click)="next()">{{ 'Next' | translate }}</button>
```

I want to add another color scheme like `hint` or `info`.

```
<button mat-button color="hint">{{ 'Hint' | translate }}</button>
```

Where can I define those colors?

Answer (score 0):

Here is two different solutions :

**1. Edit the palette of your Angular Material theme**

If you want to edit this information globally to your application, you can create your own Angular Material Theme and extending the one you are using. More informations about Angular Material theming : https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

In a less proper way, you can also edit the `style.css` of your application to apply global style to your app.

**2. Edit the style of the children component**

In your case, you maybe want to edit the color of your input without changing every inputs using the same color in your app (ex: `color="primary"`).

You can use `::ng-deep` to apply style on a children component.

> `ng-deep` is currently deprecated but there is no replacement for the moment. Here is what the documentation says: "Keep using ::ng-deep and its alternatives until a replacement is created - the deprecation is just an early notice so that people aren't blindsided whenever the actual change materializes."

Comment: To my specific tag. How do I then define the `color="hint"`